# Android / Turning on dangerous permissions automatically without user's consultation

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, runtime-permissions, dangerous-permissions

```
requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]), 101);
```

In Android, after Marshmallow version, is there any way to turn on dangerous permissions like accessing device's fine location, camera or microphone automatically without user's consultation? If not, why is it so? What is the reason behind it?

I wish I would be able to closely monitor my iPad by using my smartphone while I am at office and it would be good if it were possible to do it without user's consultation. I also know that once an app is installed and if a user accepts for a dangerous permission at least once, then it would not prompt for it again.

By the way, why it is known as dangerous permission and not something like sensitive permission, as it intrudes user's privacy and makes it possible to access stored files on any given user's mobile device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dangerous permissions**

Dangerous permissions cover areas where the app wants data or resources that involve the user's private information, or could potentially affect the user's stored data or the operation of other apps. For example, the ability to read the user's contacts is a dangerous permission. If an app declares that it needs a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly grant the permission to the app. Until the user approves the permission, your app cannot provide functionality that depends on that permission.

To use a dangerous permission, your app must prompt the user to grant permission at runtime. For more details about how the user is prompted, see Request prompt for dangerous permission.